# Convert IST to EST time zone format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert my IST datetime to EST datetime. I tried a few ways but am unable to do it.

`SELECT (CAST('2022-07-25 03:06' AS DateTime)) at time zone 'US Eastern Standard Time' AS DATETIME`

Output:

```
2022-07-25 03:06:00.000 -04:00 output is same
```

Required output in EST timezone

Thanks in advance

Comment: "results are not expected" please show your sample data, your desired results and your actual results.

Comment: Please add the output as it should be for EST (don't make us try and work it out).

Comment: I wonder if you read this in the docs `When inputdate is provided without offset information, the function applies the offset of the time zone assuming that inputdate is in the target time zone.`

Comment: How do you know which offset it is? Bear in mind DST and duplicate times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For offsets between time zones to work correctly you need to start with time zone-aware data types, such as [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql).

For example the following parses a time, including time zone offset, into a `datetimeoffset` value:

```sql
select cast('2022-07-25 03:06:00.000 +5:30' as datetimeoffset) as IST
```

Which outputs:

| IST |
| --- |
| 2022-07-25 03:06:00.0000000 +05:30 |

And to convert that to a time in the US EST time zone:

```sql
select cast('2022-07-25 03:06 +05:30' AS datetimeoffset) at time zone 'US Eastern Standard Time' as EST
```

Which outputs:

| EST |
| --- |
| 2022-07-24 17:36:00.0000000 -04:00 |